# Removing a Column from a boost::multi_array in an array_view

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to create a `boost::multi_array<double, 2>::array_view<2>::type` with one fewer column than the original `boost::multi_array<double, 2>`. I can use `index_range` to perform all sorts of indexing operations, but it seems that they all require that the created view is a contiguous block in the original array. For instance, I could do a sub-selection of columns with something like this:

```
typedef boost::multi_array::types::index_range range;
boost::multi_array<double, 2>::array_view<2>::type view = 
       original[boost::indices[range()][range() > 2]];
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to do something like this:

```
boost::multi_array<double, 2>::array_view<2>::type view = 
       original[boost::indices[range()][range() != 3]];
```

Is there a way to create a non-contiguous view such as this, or perhaps to efficiently merge two separate views into the same array?

Comment: Or perhaps the even more general question is just how to assign a view to a new multi_array?